# iOS Angle Right/Left 3D Effect

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I'm looking to Animate a UIView and give it some 3D Effects.

I've experimented with `CATransform3DMakeRotation()` but can't seem to get the correct effect.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Where the red view is moving from side to side with a 3d perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer, but something to point you to right direction. [Tumbljack has a nice tutorial, sample project and video](http://tumbljack.com/post/176535888/3d-objects-in-objective-c-with-catransformlayer) on how to do 3D transformation on a view.

You can try with the following properties as mentioned in that.

```
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radian, x, y, z);
```

or

```
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -zDistance;
```

Try tweaking the sample code to get the desired output on your `UIVIew`. His tutorial is to have a complete 3D cube/sphere transformation and in your case you might need only the left and right movement from that.